# Asp.net postback in gridview

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application i have a gridview control, in which i added a template column with fileupload control.
And outside the gridview in the page i have a button control which performs some task.
My issue is that when i click the button, the file which i chosen via file upload control in gridview has get refreshed and the file path vanishes.
How can i stop refreshing the gridiew when i click the button.
Button is not inside the grid.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "abcd";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any postback happening when the button outside the gridview is clicked?

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Ajax, then place your gridview in a separate update panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File upload control is not designed to maintain filepath on poskback.. but you can have a workaround of it.. try storing filepaths in session variables.. i know it bit clumsy but seems like the only way to do this.. one more thing you can do to lessen you effort is to create a UserControl that will manage this for you...

```
//If first time page is submitted and we have file in FileUpload control but not in session
        // Store the values to SEssion Object
        if (Session["FileUpload1"] == null && FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
}
// Next time submit and Session has values but FileUpload is Blank
        // Return the values from session to FileUpload
        else if (Session["FileUpload1"] != null && (! FileUpload1.HasFile))
{
FileUpload1 = (FileUpload) Session["FileUpload1"];
Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
}
// Now there could be another sictution when Session has File but user want to change the file
        // In this case we have to change the file in session object
        else if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
}
```

for more info

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/101834/How-to-Maintain-FileUpload-Control-s-State-after-P.aspx

Regards

Answer (score 0):

File upload control will never persists its value between postbacks.
You can maintain a Label field in your GridView which holds the path of the file uploded via FileUpload control. When you click on the button outside your GridView, copy the values from FileUpload control to lable.